# How many conjugacy classes of elementary abelian subgroups of order $p^2$ does $\operatorname{GL}_{4}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)$ have?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$Let $f\in \Hom((\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^2,\GL_{4}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z))$ be an injective homomorphism. What is the number of isomorphism classes of semidirect products of the form $$(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^{4}\rtimes_{f}
(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^2?$$
This allows us to compute the number of conjugacy classes of elementary abelian subgroups of order $p^2$ in $\GL_{4}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)=\Aut((\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^{4})$ which is in fact not easy.

Comment: The title seems distinct from the question (even if there is a relation). If there is a reduction from the main question to the title question, please incorporate in the question.

Comment: I am not sure that I believe that knowing just the number of isomorphism classes of semidirect products will enable you to compute the number of conjugacy classes of subgroups $C_p^2$ in ${\rm GL}
(4,p)$. Not all of the homomorphisms $f$ are injective. Also, it is not clear (to me) that the isomorphism of two of the semidirect products would imply  the conjugacy of the corresponding subgroups of ${\rm GL}
(4,p)$.

Comment: @Derek Holt, thank you for your comment. Of course f is injective.

Comment: If it's any help, the answers (to both questions) when $p=2,3,5,7$ are $6,10,12,12$. That's as far as I can go with naive computation.

Comment: Note that for $p=2,3$ there are elements of order $p^2$ too.