# How many conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups of order $p^2$ does $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)$ have?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, conjugacy-classes

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$Let $f\in \Hom((\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z),\GL_{n}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z))$ be an injective homomorphism.  What is the number of isomorphism classes of semidirect products of the form $$(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^{n}\rtimes_{f}(\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z)?$$

This allows us to compute the number of conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups of order $p^2$ in $\GL_{n}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)=\Aut((\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^{n})$.

Comment: Close to duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375835/number-of-conjugacy-classes-of-elementary-abelian-subgroups-of-order-p2-does (asked 1 hour ago). Please rather edit the initial question to amend it. If these are meant to be distinct question, they are very close hence please relate them.

Comment: (more precisely the previous question is $n=4$ and hasn't been answered besides some small values of $p$, in the comments)

Comment: I fact, in the previous question we deal we elementary Abelian subgroup of rank $2$ in the general linear group, which can be complicated. I this question, I am looking for cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$ and then it is equivalent to compute the number of conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$ which is not the case for elementary abelian subgroup.

Comment: This problem seems very difficult, and it is also hard to understand how knowing the exact number of classes of cyclic subgroups of order $p^2$ in ${\rm GL}(n,p)$ would help with anything. On the other hand, I can see that having a n asymptotic estimate for this number or perhaps an upper bound might be helpful. So I guess I am really asking for more motivation.

Comment: The title question is mostly trivial because $x^{p^2}-1$ splits completely in $\Bbb{Z/pZ}$ so there is a basis putting the generator of your cyclic group in Jordan normal form.

Comment: Yes, the title question is answered by the number of Jordan normal forms for unipotent matrices in which all Jordan blocks have size at most $p^{2}$ and at least one Jordan block has size greater than $p$. Thus it is basically a question about partitions of $n$ with that constraint on the sizes of the parts.

Comment: Of course, Jordan normal forms are for elements rather than subgroups, but I think all generators of the same cyclic subgroup have the same normal form, so that makes no difference. I withdraw my comment about this particular question being difficult, but the earlier question about subgroups $C_p^2$ seems difficult, and it would be intersting to see some motivation.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes indeed, at least for cyclic $p$-groups in characteristic $p$, generators of the same cyclic subgroup do indeed have the same Jordan normal form (as those generators are powers of each other). I agree that the question would become much more difficult if we considered a non-cyclic $p$-group of order $p^{2}$.